# How Create user,group and permission in admin panel by using codeiniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am new to this framwork kindly anyone help me, how to create user,group and permissions in admin panel by using codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You can check Ion Auth here: [github link](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth)

Pretty simple, fast integration and has plenty of features to work with.